# How do I unit test writing to a CSV file?

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

I am currently writing a test for a django script that writes some audit log entries to a CSV file. The system takes one CSV file, parses its contents, then adds entries based on the selections within, and saves it again once its all done.

The outline of the test is as follows:

```
class ProjectAuditReportExporterTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    (...)
    def test_csv_generation(self):
        (...)

        mock_csv_writer = MagicMock()
        mock_csv_writer.writerow = MagicMock()
        with patch("external.exporters.csv_overwrite", return_value=mock_csv_writer) as mock_csv_overwrite:
            it = ImportTask.objects.create(
                organization=self.organization,
                user=self.user,
                data="force_delete",
                file=ContentFile(csv_buffer.getvalue(), "test_audit_report_exporter.csv"),
                importer="TasksAuditReportExporter",
            )
            mock_csv_overwrite.assert_called_once_with(it.file, "Task Audit Report")
            mock_csv_writer.writerow.assert_called()
```

The applicable bits of code for the export process are as follows:

```
@contextmanager
def csv_overwrite(file, filename_prefix) -> csv.writer:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file, io.TextIOWrapper(
        temp_file, encoding="utf-8-sig", write_through=True
    ) as text_file:
        yield csv.writer(text_file)
        temp_file.flush()
        temp_file.seek(0)
        file.save(f"{filename_prefix}_{now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.csv", temp_file)

(...)

class EventsAuditReportExporter(BaseCSVImporter):
    def _handle_row(self, row):
        log_entries = self._logs_filter(LogEntry.objects.get_for_model(Event), start_date, end_date)

        with csv_overwrite(self.task.file, "Event Audit Report") as csv_writer:
            csv_writer.writerow(
                (
                    "Event ID",
                    "Action date",
                    "Action actor",
                    "Action",
                    "Event name",
                    "Event date",
                )
            )

            for log_entry in log_entries.prefetch_related("actor", "version"):
            field_dict = log_entry.version.field_dict
                if field_dict:
                    csv_writer.writerow(
                        (
                            log_entry.object_id,
                            log_entry.created.isoformat(),
                            log_entry.actor,
                            log_entry.action,
                            field_dict.get("title"),
                            field_dict.get("date"),
                        )
                    )
```

I know there are appropriate log entries available, my debugger will always get into the `csv_writer.writerow` line with out issue.

The issue that I have is that the `mock_csv_writer.writerow.assert_called()` will always be false, I'm unsure of the way to mock the writerow (or if I even have to)